# Blur of the last app appears on screen

Tags: screen

I've watched a physics video and I realized it is still showing part of screen. Why it originates?
Edit :
screenshot doesn't include the blur of the last video Ive watched

[image: look carefully at left side]

Comment: Reboot your device.